# Mariadb 11.3.2 + PHP: Server sent charset (0) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, mariadb, mysqlnd

If you try to connect with PHP PDO to the newest Version of mariadb (11.3.2) you will see this error and the client will be unable to connect:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset (0) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason: Mariadb sends a value that was unset before. While this is perfectly inline with the protocol since 2004, the mysql driver of php still implements a status of the protocol of this value as before of 2004, and thus will crash.

You need to unset collation-server and character-set-server or set it to a compatible value in the server config until this is fixed.

MariaDB Docker Image:
Just add

```
command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
```

Normal Install:
Just remove the line character-set-collations = utf8mb4=uca1400_ai_ci from /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

More Info: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/13452

Comment: Container image [workaround](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/pull/565) and [reissued](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/16293) (currently going through [ci](https://doi-janky.infosiftr.net/) somewhere so will be up in a few hrs).

Answer (score -1):

minor adjustment to @Alpix's command above:

```
command: mariadbd --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
```

Comment: its not needed. When options beginning with `-` are on cmd, `mariadbd` is assumed. [ref](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/11.3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L670).

Comment: This should be made as an edit to the other answer not a new answer